# How to list my Sales Reps for a customer on one line?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have some orders on NetSuite that has 2 or more sales reps getting commission for the sale. I want to create a search (if possible) that would return only one line with all sales reps' names separated by a comma (John Smith, Jane Doe, etc.) instead of returning 2 (or more) separate lines for the same order but different sales rep name under the Sales Rep column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the undocumented `NS_CONCAT()` function in your saved search.  If you're using sales teams and your sales reps are returned in the Sales Team Member field, you would combine them like this:

- Group your search results by Sales Order (and any other field you need in the results).
- Add a Formula(text) field to the results, set the summary type to 'Minimum' and set the formula to `NS_CONCAT({salesteammember})`

This will combine all of your sales reps into a single field separated by a comma.