# System note data in one line on saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

We have a three level approval for purchase orders. I have received a requirement to show who approved at each level and the timestamp against every PO in saved search,

When I started creating this search, I am struggling to get the data for every PO in one line, as the system note data has one line each for every approval.

Can you please advise on how to get these multiplelines on a single line for every PO?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check out the undocumented `NS_CONCAT` function for saved searches.

Here's an example answered earlier:
[How to list my Sales Reps for a customer on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921327/how-to-list-my-sales-reps-for-a-customer-on-one-line/66921975#66921975)